# invalid conversion from const char * to char * in Linux with Ternary Operator

Tags: c++, linux

Example 1:

```
char* message = ( m_message != NULL ? m_message : "" );
```

above line gives compiler error as invalid conversion from const char* to char*. in g++ compiler. but the below piece of code works.

Example 2:

```
char* message;
if(m_message)
    message = m_message;
else
    message = "";
```

Why do I get a compiler error with `g++` in the first example but not the second? Both ways work fine in Windows.

Comment: `""` is a `const char *`

Comment: that line of code is enough i guess..
problem is there in both c & c++ on Linux
m_message is of `char*` type

Comment: The answer is different in C and C++, since string literals in C are of type `char*` and you wouldn't get errors, but in C++ they are of type `const char*` and you will get errors. Anyway the proper solution is the same for both languages, declare `message` as `const`.

Comment: @SanthoshKumar I'd recommend to edit your question to explain it (that is, that you are aware of the solution, but what you are asking for is the reason behind this different behaviour). Great find anyway, +1.

Answer (score 3):

The string literal -> `char*` conversion is allowed (but deprecated) only if it is direct - you can't let the value "pass through" somewhere else to decay into a `const char*`.

Your second code is a conversion directly from a string literal to a `char*`, which is "only" deprecated.

The first one is first a pointer decay to `const char*` - the result of `m_message != NULL ? m_message : ""` is a `const char*` - and then an attempt to convert the resulting `const char*` to a `char*`, which isn't allowed.

This code also produces an error, for the same reason:

```
const char* empty() { return ""; }

char* message;
if(m_message)
    message = m_message;
else
    message = empty();
```

Answer (score 0):

The type of string literal in C++ is not "char *", but "const char[n]", i.e. array of const characters (in this case const char[1]). The conversion to char * was initially allowed for backward compatibility with C library calls, but now it is deprecated, because it is not safe.

I get "-Werror=write-strings" in both cases with g++.